# Why does xrandr report some values that it subsequently cannot find?

Tags: xrandr

Why does `xrandr --query` include some values that `xrandr --mode` subsequently cannot find?

```
$ xrandr --query
...
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1440x810 
xrandr: cannot find mode 1440x810
```

Full output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.96    50.00    59.94    59.93    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1400x1050     74.76    59.98  
   1600x900      59.94    59.95    60.00*   59.82  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    60.00    50.00    59.94    59.74  
   1024x768      75.05    60.04    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   960x720       75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   720x576       50.00  
   700x525       74.76    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x512       75.02    60.02  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    75.00    72.81    75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       70.08  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       75.00  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DVI-D-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and show the **entire** output of `xrandr --query`?